# table layout TextViews show text vertically vs horizontally wether they are in or out of focus

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I am fairly new to eclipse and java and android dev. I have spent hours searching for an answer to this dilemma to no avail.  I have a table on 3 activities of my app that consist of vertical or horizontal alteration of textViews and editText elements ie: t,e t,e t,e or tttt,eeee.

Everything looks good in eclipse i have double checked layout weight and gravity but when these activities run on emulator the text in each textView will appear vertical until i bring focus to the parent table by selecting a editText element within the same table. Once i do this the text returns to the correct horizontal fashion i originally placed it in but again reverses if focus is taken away from the table?  can anyone help me?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/FireScreen">
    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/diamondplate"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView 
    android:background="@drawable/buttonfade" 
    android:id="@+id/FireScreenTitle" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:layout_width="150dip" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="FIRE INFO"
    android:textSize="21sp" 
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
    <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FireScreenTitle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/FIfiretable">
    <TableRow>
<TextView   
android:id="@+id/FIfiretype" 
android:text="Fire Type" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/FItypespin"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_weight="1">
</Spinner>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
<TextView   
android:id="@+id/FIareatype" 
android:text="Fire Area" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/FIareaspin"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_weight="1">
</Spinner>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
<TextView   
android:id="@+id/FIactiontype" 
android:text="Action Taken" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/FIactionspin"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_weight="1">
</Spinner>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FIfiretable"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/FIcalltable">
    <TableRow>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIinvolved" 
android:text="% Involved" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIwater" 
android:text="H2O Gal." 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIinvolvedtext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
    <EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIwatertext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIfoam" 
android:text="Foam Gal." 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIacres" 
android:text="Acres" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIfoamtext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
    <EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIacrestext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIcasualties" 
android:text="Casualties" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/FIfatalities" 
android:text="Fatalities" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
    <EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIcasualtiestext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
<EditText 
android:text="" 
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:numeric="integer" 
android:id="@+id/FIfatalitiestext"
android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>
</TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/FInotes"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonfade"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="Notes"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/FIcalltable"
    android:layout_below="@+id/FIcalltable"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/FInotestext" 
    android:text="Additional Information:"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/FInotes"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/FInotes" 
    android:layout_height="200dip" 
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"   
    android:lines="5">
    </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/fire_thumb"
    android:id="@+id/FImenutable">
    <TableRow>
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/FIUnitsStart"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:text="UNITS"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/FIMainResume"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:text="MAIN"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just ran your layout XML and I'm not getting any vertical text appearing.  Are you able to post a screenshot of the problem, and a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: actually it is only on handset emulation, but what i want is                     "this is text"                inside textView  and what I am getting is vertical t(over)h(over)i(over)s ... etc. when the activity is created . . .  however when I click on a spinner for instance, outside of this tableLayout then the orientation of the text returns to how the XML was written. and visa versa

Comment: Spinner? There's no spinner in the example code you posted. At any rate, what you posted is insufficient to replicate the problem you're reporting.  I suggest posting the COMPLETE MINIMAL code necessary to replicate your problem.

Comment: I apologize @Thane I have now posted the entire layout which contains 3 spinners and if you select a spinner on a handset emulation the text in the textviews of the table goes vertical until you click on the table somehow like a edittext.

Comment: I ran your latest layout code.  Still no vertical text appearing -- all text inputs are horizontal and do not resize to one character width.  (The layout does have an issue where the two bottom buttons always float on top of the view.)

Comment: that was intentional with the buttons . .  . I am emulating on an evo 4g ... any suggestions as to why that may be happening for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAHA!!! I have figured it out! lol I had two table layouts within the same parent layout and therefore when one was given process focus over the other.... text alteration. I fixed this by placing table2 within another layout:) I.E.:

Old Way:

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TableLayout1>
            <TableLayout1>

            <TableLayout2>
            <TableLayout2>
        <RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
```

New (successful) Way:

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <TableLayout1>
            <TableLayout1>

            <LinearLayout2>
                <TableLayout2>
                <TableLayout2>
            <LinearLayout2>
        <RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
```

Now neither TableLayout is robbing focus from the other in the same layout . . . I am not sure why I had to do this but hey it works now lol